# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException errorr

Tags: java

I'm creating a postfix calculator. I've read elsewhere and the issues usually are because of the Scanner. So, maybe that will be a head start for you? I have a `Calculator.java` class and a `CalculatorTester.java` class below.

Code:

```
public class Calculator {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    }

    public int postfix(String string){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);
        LLStack<Integer> stack = new LLStack<Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
                stack.push(scanner.nextInt());
            } else {
                if (scanner.next().equals("+")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x+y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("-")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x-y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("*")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x*y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("/")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x/y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("%")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x%y);
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.pop();
    }
}
```

```
public class Calculator {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
    }

    public int postfix(String string){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);
        LLStack<Integer> stack = new LLStack<Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
                stack.push(scanner.nextInt());
            } else {
                if (scanner.next().equals("+")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x+y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("-")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x-y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("*")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x*y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("/")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x/y);
                }
                if (scanner.next().equals("%")){
                    y = stack.pop();
                    x = stack.pop();
                    stack.pop();
                    stack.push(x%y);
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.pop();
    }
}
```

Terminal output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Calculator.postfix(Calculator.java:23)
    at CalculatorTester.main(CalculatorTester.java:4)
```

Comment: Why did you remove your code from your question?  Doing so made your question useless to future readers. I had no idea what Edgar was talking about, until I noticed you had edited your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how really Scanner class works. But, what I know is that Scanner read line per line, and not character by character (I'm not sure if there is a way to read like that).
So, you first mistake is you are reading a String in one line, so, when you do this:

```
scanner.next()
```

The scanner really returns your full string `"345*+"`. You can fix this, using `\n` in each character:

```
calc.postfix("3\n4\n5\n*\n+");
```

Now, inside your postfix method, you have a mistake about reading with scanner:

```
else {
            if (scanner.next().equals("+")){}
            if (scanner.next().equals("-")){}
....
}
```

If you see, you are using inside the if conditions `scanner.next()`. When you use that method, you are moving the pointer of the Scanner to the next input.

For example, you have the next input: `"Hello\nWorld\nFuzz"`
When you use `scanner.next()` the first time, the pointer will be in `"Hello"`.
The second time you use it, will be in `"World"` and finally when read `"Fuzz"` and you use `scanner.next()` the pointer will be in the EOF(end of file).
Then, the `scanner.hasNext()` method will return false.

To fix that mistake, you have to assign what `scanner.next()` returns to a String variable, and then, use that one for comparing.

Your code must be like this:

```
private int x;
private int y;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    System.out.println(calc.postfix("3\n4\n5\n*\n+"));
}

public int postfix(String string){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(string);
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        
        if (scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
        
            stack.push(scanner.nextInt());

        } else {
            String next=scanner.next();
        
            if (next.equals("+")){
                y = stack.pop();
                x = stack.pop();
                
                stack.push(x+y);
            }
            if (next.equals("-")){
                y = stack.pop();
                x = stack.pop();
                
                stack.push(x-y);
            }
            if (next.equals("*")){
                y = stack.pop();
                x = stack.pop();
                
                stack.push(x*y);
            }
            if (next.equals("/")){
                y = stack.pop();
                x = stack.pop();
                
                stack.push(x/y);
            }
            if (next.equals("%")){
                y = stack.pop();
                x = stack.pop();
                
                stack.push(x%y);
            }
                            
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();
}
```

> I had to remove the lines `stack.pop();` inside the `postfix()` method, because that was causing an EmptyStackException

Comment: Thank you! That was pretty clear to follow, helped a ton. Cheers